# MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) leads to Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.String Mockito cannot mock/spy because : - final class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

so I'm building a test class and have the following setup function:

```
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         //do other set up stuff
    }
```

When I run the test class without `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`, everything works as expected. However, as soon as I want to add mocks and add the initMocks statement, I get the following error message:

```
Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.String
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.String
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.withBefores(DefaultInternalRunner.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:78)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:84)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
```

It's so confusing because I don't believe I used strings in there? I stripped down the class to a single test asserting that 1 == 1 so I know for a fact the error doesn't come from the tests. FYI, that also happens when I try to use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your entire test class?

Comment: I would assume that there is a String field with `@Mock` or `@Spy` annotation in your test class - if so, try to remove the annotation. As jnorman said - it would be easier to help if you added your test class code.